# Pop-up window from Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I bought the pc from a friend who had Ubuntu 11.10 installed. I upgraded to 12.04 LTS. Ubuntu asks me to sign up, which I do, with each of my different
e-mail accounts and respective codes. Nothing happens since Ubuntu does not recognize any one of them. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Sing up to what? I'd recommend wiping the HDD, and reinstalling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean Ubuntu One account?  If so, you can create a new one.  I believe that's the way it worked for me.